# Internal Server Error .htaccess -

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have migrated my web page to a own hosting created with xubuntu. I have moved everything but at the time of publishing new content, I have the error of "'LimitInternalRecursion' in my log,
I have tried to uninstall the plugins (all), change the theme and it does not work for me. in my .htaccess I have the following configuration:

[image: htacces]

**ERROR LOG:**

[image: log]

any ideas?

Comment: It look likes your htaccess is looping

Comment: Try removing the # from this line RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should charter "#" from the line 5. The .htaccess should looks as this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

More information about the WordPress' htaccess file you can find on the link below:
https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess